# Show/Hide Angular confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the pseudo code

Web App: nametester.html 
Uses: AngularJS 
Model:
 - strName (which stores a String value)

--- Steps:
  1: Assign strName using ng-model with the prompt:
     'Please enter your name:'

2: ng-show (if)"strName == '—add your name here—'"

3: Output 'Awesome name!'

4: ng-hide (else)"strName == '—add your name here—'"

5: Output strName, ' is a not my name'

Use the lowercase filter to convert the value of a variable into lowercase before you compare.

And my code

## Name Tester App

```
    <p><label for="name">Please Enter Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" data-ng-model="strName"/></p>
    <span>{{strVar | lowercase}}</span>
        <p>
            <span data-ng-show ="strName =='Ben'"> Awesome Name</span>
            <span data-ng-hide ="strName =='Someone'">{{strName}}, is not your name</span>
        </p>
```

But it doesn't work. I am seeing ", is not your name" even when the text input is blank and how to filter input to lowercase values before its compared.

Show works. When I put my name I do get output in the format

Awesome Name! Ben, is not your name

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr?

Comment: Remove the white spaces between `data-ng-show` and `=`, and `data-ng-hide` and `=`.

Comment: @str tried, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `{{strVar | lowercase}}` will not modify your variable value. It will only display in lowercase for that particulary usage.

Your comparison inside ngShow/ngHide should be:

```
<span ng-show="strName.toLowerCase() == 'Ben'.toLowerCase()" />;
```

Comment: Thanks. And what about the ng-hide span ? It appears even when filled is blank and it continues to appear after the name is matched like this Awesome Name! Ben, is not your name

Comment: It will hide only if the input name is 'Someone'. You probably want it to be <span data-ng-hide ="strName !='Ben'">{{strName}}, is not your name</span>

Comment: @henrikmerlander when I do that it never shows that statement even if I type wrong.

Comment: then change to ng-show instead, it all comes down to what you are trying to achieve, which I do not know.

Comment: Can't don't you see the pseudocode I have provided at the top ? My code must meet them.

Comment: @henrikmerlander hey bro thanks, I figured out the way using your example the correct code would be - <span data-ng-hide="strName.toLowerCase() == 'Ben'.toLowerCase()">{{strName}}, is not your name</span>

Comment: Unfortunately I was told I cannot user a method and must use filter lowercase before the condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclusively show or hide one of the spans, then just use ng-show and ng-hide with the same expression inside. Like this:

```
<span data-ng-show="strName =='Ben'"> Awesome Name</span>
```

and

```
<span data-ng-hide="strName =='Ben'">{{strName}}, is not your name</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all we should know what is **ng-show=""** and **ng-hide=""** in angularJS.

By Simple term 
The ng-show directive shows or hides an HTML element. If the condition is true then it will **show** the content. If not then it won't. So we can use ng-show for both show and hide.

The ng-hide directive shows or hides an HTML element. If the condition is true then it will **hide** the content. If not then it won't. So we can use ng-hide for both show and hide.
By referring these advice your making small mistake by comparing strings in the directive itself. Kindly remove those conditions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='nametest'>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title> Show Hide</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='strName'>

 <p><label for="name">Please Enter Your Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" data-ng-model="strName1" > </p>
 <span>{{strName1 | lowercase}}</span>

 <span data-ng-show ="temp"> Awesome Name</span>
  <span data-ng-show ="!temp"> Is not My Name</span>

</body>
</html>

**Controller :**



var app = angular.module('nametest',[]);

app.controller('strName',function($scope){
  $scope.strName1 = 'Ben';
  var my_Name = $scope.strName1;
  $scope.temp = false;
  if(my_Name == "Ben"){
    console.log('Success');
    $scope.temp = true;
  }

});
```

For more details visit..
https://jsbin.com/pokukudoyo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Actually that's not acceptable. We aren't allowed to use controller yet. and we must use show and hide statement. Check my pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

In the `ng-hide` you need to check that `strName` does not exist OR that it is set to 'Ben'.

Do do this we pass this expression `!strName || strName == 'Ben'` to the `ng-hide` directive. You can run snippet below.

```js
angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

      <p><label for="name">Please Enter Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" data-ng-model="strName"/></p>
    <span>{{strVar | lowercase}}</span>
        <p>
            <span data-ng-show ="strName =='Ben'"> Awesome Name</span>
            <span data-ng-hide ="!strName || strName == 'Ben'">{{strName}}, is not your name</span>
        </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple way you can do this

`<span ng-show="strName.toLowerCase() == 'ben'" />;`